# How to find out where I sent my coins in 2011?

Tags: wallet, lost-bitcoins

I got into Bitcoin a while ago. 2011-ish. I build a miner and got a number of coins.
My storage wallet shows that I moved 4 coins to {long code} but I don't remember where I sent them. Is there any way to find them with that code? 
I think I was sending it to a trading site or some kind of online wallet. Maybe my mining client? I honestly just can't remember.
I would be willing to send a coin your way if I am able to recover the lost coins with your advice.
Thanks in advance.
-someone who should have paid more attention to what he was doing
(at least i didn't pay 10,000 for a pizza...)

Comment: If you post the addresses where the coins where sent to, then we can try to track them down. Your question above just says "{long code}", so actually put the bitcoin address where the coins where sent to and any other details (date/time).

Comment: Its not letting me comment anymore because I registered and now don't have 50 reputation even though I posted the original. This is the link to the "detailed info about the block with the transaction
https://bitcoinchain.com/block_explorer/block/135230/ 17doDZAh6qQLbYtj9zqXx7dFm3Js82Zpa2 is the address i sent it to. on 7/7/2011 at 17:54

Comment: You can merge your accounts: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Check your email account around that time to see if you created an account on a Bitcoin exchange, or if you got a deposit confirmation.

To find it more quickly, you could try to search your emails for the amount you sent, the address that you sent from, and the address that you sent to, because either might be contained in such a deposit confirmation or payment request.

As Jannes mentioned, you could also try to search for the receiving address on a block explorer, to see if the address or a succeeding address where the money was forwarded to is a known entity.

Unfortunately, the most commonly used exchanges from 2011 are now defunct. But it may be worth seeing if you sent it to a Bitstamp account as that was founded in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

You can Google the address in case it's a well known address (for donations or scammers).

Other than that try some block explorers to see if they say anything. Look at where the coins went after your transaction. Are they still sitting there?

Hope it wasn't mtgox where you sent them.

Comment: After about 2 weeks of trying I got them on the phone/email and they didnt have any record on the transfer or my account so I don't think it was them. I am fairly sure it was my mining client. I haven't used them to pay for anything ever. I have only transferred between accounts controlled by myself.

Comment: Holy Crap... Googling it worked. Well, i think it worked. It showed up on Bitcoinchain.com. Is that a site that just searches the block data? Does it help that it showed up there?

Comment: Looks like a typical blockchain explorer site yeah. blockchain.info, blocktrail.com ... Some may have a little bit more info on addresses than others, so could try a few different ones. You can try any of dozens. You should be able to see if the coins are still in that address or if they have since moved on. If they have moved on they could be on some online wallet or exchange (and possibly gone by now). If they haven't moved on, you may have made a wallet yourself (software or on paper).